# What's the minimum amount of bytes that an azure blob can contain?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

The [Microsoft documentation on Azure Blobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691964.aspx) clearly explains that you have a maximum block size (and a maximum number of blocks in each block/append/page blob), but it does not mention any lower bound.

Suppose you have a large number of small binary blobs (from 10 to 512 bytes), is the storage accounted on the exact disk space occupied by the blob data, or is there a minimum chunk size? Or a known fixed "per block" overhead?

For example, is it possible to create a 10 byte block blob? How much space is it actually accounted on billing for it: 10 bytes or another minimum amount (say 4k)?

Is such a minimum block size exists, how does it apply to Append Blobs? And to Page blobs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by Fabrizio in the answer, **minimum size of a blob can be zero bytes** but even a zero byte blob occupies space that you're charged for. From the blog post by storage team here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/07/08/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity/, this is how the storage space for a blob is calculated:

> 124 bytes + Len(BlobName) * 2 bytes +  For-Each Metadata[3 bytes +
>   Len(MetadataName) + Len(Value)] +  8 bytes + number of committed and
>   uncommitted blocks * Block ID Size in bytes +  SizeInBytes(data in
>   unique committed data blocks stored) +  SizeInBytes(data in
>   uncommitted data blocks)

Not to mention that you would incur transaction charges for each blob you save.

Answer (score 0):

The lower limit is... zero :)
Only for testing, I created a 0 byte and a 1 byte BlockBlob without any problem.
Update: however a zero byte blockblob has a cost.

Comment: So you think that a zero byte block is free of charge?

Comment: @GiacomoTesio At less than 3 cents per GB/month, even a billion 1-byte blobs will be nearly free. Is this really a concern?

Comment: If you store 100 million 3 byte blobs you will be billed for way more than 300mb due to the about 200 byte overhead