# Azure AppService Logs Warning Maximum size for region

Tags: .net, azure, memory, warnings, azure-appservice

I having this warning on my logs and don't have a clue about it, or what it means.

Basycally from time to time a get hundreeds of lines like this:

```
2022-10-04T10:45:23.796229138Z ** (process:53): WARNING **: 10:45:23.795: Requested 0 bytes. Maximum size for region is 262144 bytes.

2022-10-04T10:45:23.810953303Z 

2022-10-04T10:45:23.811014403Z ** (process:53): WARNING **: 10:45:23.810: Requested 0 bytes. Maximum size for region is 262144 bytes.

2022-10-04T10:45:23.823955748Z 

2022-10-04T10:45:23.823975948Z ** (process:53): WARNING **: 10:45:23.823: Requested 0 bytes. Maximum size for region is 262144 bytes.

2022-10-04T10:45:23.836791491Z 

2022-10-04T10:45:23.836858592Z ** (process:53): WARNING **: 10:45:23.836: Requested 0 bytes. Maximum size for region is 262144 bytes.

2022-10-04T10:45:23.842492755Z 

2022-10-04T10:45:23.842510755Z ** (process:53): WARNING **: 10:45:23.842: Requested 0 bytes. Maximum size for region is 262144 bytes.

2022-10-04T10:45:23.856046707Z 

2022-10-04T10:45:23.856131908Z ** (process:53): WARNING **: 10:45:23.855: Requested 0 bytes. Maximum size for region is 262144 bytes.

2022-10-04T10:45:23.865767715Z 

2022-10-04T10:45:23.865815216Z ** (process:53): WARNING **: 10:45:23.865: Requested 0 bytes. Maximum size for region is 262144 bytes.

2022-10-04T10:45:23.875841928Z 

2022-10-04T10:45:23.875918429Z ** (process:53): WARNING **: 10:45:23.875: Requested 0 bytes. Maximum size for region is 262144 bytes.

2022-10-04T10:45:23.886996952Z 

2022-10-04T10:45:23.887175554Z ** (process:53): WARNING **: 10:45:23.886: Requested 0 bytes. Maximum size for region is 262144 bytes.

2022-10-04T10:45:23.903502537Z 

2022-10-04T10:45:23.903526837Z ** (process:53): WARNING **: 10:45:23.900: Requested 0 bytes. Maximum size for region is 262144 bytes.
```

I don't understand why it warns me about a processes that requested 0 bytes and then says the Maximum size for region like if I was getting close to that value.

Can anyone explain me what is happening?
Is it a problem I should check? If so is there a solution to fix this?

Bests

Comment: This [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits) works for your issue!

Comment: @Jahnavi thanks for the link, but if you thing they explain the problem you could open an answer highlighting the explanition of my issue so I could then approve as a correct answer

Comment: Have you checked the Azure app service memory usage? Are you archiving these logs into any storage or log analytics workspaces? And have you created `.NET` web app directly through portal or deployed from local?

Comment: Deployed it from local machine using Visual Studio, what I don't understand is the warning for the requested 0 bytes for a region with 262144  bytes..

Comment: There will be a limit per region for blob and app service. 0 bytes also block some blob storage as per my research.

Answer (score 1):

> Azure App Service Logs Warning Maximum size for region

These types of warnings would appear for a variety of reasons:
First & foremost, it is a [Bug](https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/aspose-cells-for-net-17-3-0-release-notes/) occurring frequently while obtaining service logs after deployed .NET webapp to Azure.

***Need to check & resolve:***

1. To resolve, check your regional quota and change the region to the other to avoid memory exceeded warnings as maximum byte size varies region-wise.
2. You can create a new app service plan and deploy in it.

> The total content size of all apps across all App service plans in a single resource group and region cannot exceed 500 GB as mentioned in [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits)

The actual number of App Service plans created in the area and resource group determines the file system quota for apps hosted by App Service.
Check for [App Service Planing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/app-service/windows/)

3. You can check the Azure App service memory usage as below:
   Goto

`Diagnoise & solve problem -> Availability & performance -> Memory Analysis`

You can see the current consumption of private bytes as shown here:
[image]

4. Analyze the file system storage used by your apps and app service plans.

[image]

5. Make sure that the stream logs of the files do not exceed the blob storage limit is important if you enabled diagnostic settings as it can stop log stream viewing and show this warning.
   Refer [storage limit in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-media-limits)

I've created .NET webapp using Visual Studio and deployed it to Azure:

[image]

[image]

After enabling required App service logs settings:

[image]

***I could be able to obtain the logs without any warning as shown:***

[image]

**Note**: Requested 0 bytes:- Even 0 bytes block some storage in blob as mentioned by @Gaurav Mantri [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457657/whats-the-minimum-amount-of-bytes-that-an-azure-blob-can-contain)

[Reference](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/azure-anf-blg-azure-storage-limits-at-a-glance#:%7E:text=The%20following%20limits%20are%20applied%20by%20default%20in,4%20Up%20to%20500%20volumes%20per%20Azure%20subscription)

Comment: Great work thanks for your reply, I will look further into it later and if solves my problem I will make it has accepted answer. Thanks.